# Is $\nleq$ equivalent to $>$?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, notation, alternative-proof

This seems to be the case, but if so, how can we write that an inequality is not true in general.

For example, what if I want to say, $f(x,a)$ is not always less than $f(x,b)$ for all $x$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants. In other words, $f(x,a) \leq f(x,b)$ is a false statement.

Basically, I have a hypothesis that ended up being false, and I am deciding to how write the result.

Comment: Yes. We have trichotomy: "either < or = or >" and $\le$ is "either < or =". Thus "not-($\le)$" is >.

Comment: It depends on the context.  Some things (like the real numbers) are *totally ordered*, in which case "not less than or equal" is logically equivalent to "greater than". Your terse post does not provide any details to tell us if that is true in your situation.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  How could $f(x,a)< f(x,b) $ $\textit {always}$ be true?  If, say, $f(x, 1)<f(x,2)$ then $f(x,2)$ is not less than $f(x,1)$.

Comment: I edited my question. I mean for all $x$ given some $a$ and some $b$. So, if $f(x,y) = x + y$, then if $y=a$ and $y=b$ where $a<b$, then $f(x,a) < f(x,b)$ for all $x$. Functions exist where $a<b$ would not imply $f(x,a) < f(x,b)$, but $f(x,a) \geq f(x,b)$ isn't true either.

Comment: Well, then your inequality should include the quantifiers.  It is perfectly possible that, say, $f(1,1)<f(1,2)$ but $f(2,1)>f(2,2)$.

Comment: "Yes. We have trichotomy: "either < or = or >" and ≤ is "either < or =". Thus "not-(≤)" is >."– Mauro ALLEGRANZA 11 mins ago.  Trichotomy is true for NUMBERS.  If we are talking about functions, then $f\le 0$ means that  $f(x)\le 0$ for ALL x. Saying $f(x)> 0$ means that $f(x)> 0$ for ALL x.  Saying $f(x)\le 0$ is NOT true means there at some values of x such f(x)> 0.

Comment: @user247327 So, you are saying that $f(x) \nleq 0$ is equivalent to $f(x) > 0$ for some $x$? If so, $f(x,a) \nleq f(x,b)$ is equivalent to $f(x,a) > f(x,b)$ for some $x$. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to two real numbers $a$ and $b$: $a \not <b$ iff $a \geq b$

But, your

> $f(x,a)$ is not always less than $f(x,b)$

is *not* equivalent to (in case that that is what you're thinking):

> $f(x,a)$ is always greater or equal to $f(x,b)$

Rather, it is equivalent to:

> $f(x,a)$ is sometimes greater or equal to $f(x,b)$

To be a little more formal:

I interpret your:

> $f(x,a)$ is not always less than $f(x,b)$

as:

> it is not the case that $f(x,a)$ is always less than $f(x,b)$

and that as:

> it is not the case that for all $x$: $f(x,a)$ is less than $f(x,b)$

which is equivalent to:

> for some $x$, it is not the case that $f(x,a)$ is less than $f(x,b)$

which by the basic equivalence between $\not <$ and $\geq$ is equivalent to:

> for some $x$, $f(x,a)$ is greater or equal to $f(x,b)$

which you can read as:

> $f(x,a)$ is sometimes greater or equal to $f(x,b)$

But this is *not* the same as:

> for all $x$, $f(x,a)$ is greater or equal to $f(x,b)$

which you can read as:

> $f(x,a)$ is always greater or equal to $f(x,b)$

Comment: More generally, this is true in any linear orders, but typically untrue in the more general context of partial orders.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I think the phrase I was looking for is “For some x, f(x,a) is greater or equal to f(x,b)”.

Comment: @Ralff You're welcome! :)